# What happened to the processor IBMQ_16_melbourne?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm a beginner, but in some books and references i use they talk about an ibm processor called IBMQ_16_melbourne, what happened to it? Can it get back up and running? Are there any other free alternatives for processing algorithms with more than 5 qubits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The machine `ibmq_16_melbourne` has been retired for a few months now, and with the open provider you won't be able to have access to machines with more than 5 qubits.

As an alternative, you can check the mock backends available in terra [right here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/tree/main/qiskit/test/mock/backends), it contains simulators that mimic exactly every machine that is or was available since the beginning of the platform. If you want to access the fake Melbourne for example :

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeMelbourne
backend = FakeMelbourne()
```

There are also simulators available on the cloud where you can compute with more qubits, see [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/admin/docs/admin/manage/simulator/).

Hope it helps! :)